# What is causing the UnboundLocalError in my PyPDF2 cmap file?

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to fix some broken python pdf splitting (PyPDF2) scripts that a coworker left behind.
I updated the PyPDF2 syntax in each script, but started running into an UnboundLocalError when trying to extract the text.

This error traces back to the cmap file within the PyPDF2 package:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (bill):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<S: private info etc/1 - Split PDF DocumentsFIX.py>", line 26, in bill
    words = page.extract_text()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py", line 1851, in extract_text
    return self._extract_text(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_page.py", line 1342, in _extract_text
    cmaps[f] = build_char_map(f, space_width, obj)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_cmap.py", line 28, in build_char_map
    map_dict, space_code, int_entry = parse_to_unicode(ft, space_code)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_cmap.py", line 194, in parse_to_unicode
    cm = prepare_cm(ft)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\_cmap.py", line 213, in prepare_cm
    if isinstance(cm, str):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cm' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the code leading up to where the error is called in one of the files:

```
def bill(directory):
    start = time.time()
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.startswith('private info'):
            print(filename)
            main = open(directory+'\\'+filename,'rb')
        else:
            continue
    mainreader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(main)
    numpg = len(mainreader.pages)
    vault = []
    mthvault = []
    yrvault = []
    meow = datetime.datetime.now()
    lgnme = meow.strftime('%m%d%y_BillLog')
    print(lgnme)
    log = open('.\\'+lgnme+'.txt','w')
    dup = []
    for i in range(0,numpg,2):
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
        page = mainreader.pages[i]
        words = page.extract_text()
```

The workaround that I found is to open the _cmap.py file and declare the variable `cm = ""` on a new line within the prepare_cm function. The scripts execute as expected with the addition.

Manually updating the cmap file is pretty hacky, so I could use some help finding the actual source of the error.

**Is this error occurring due to a dependency issue/bug, or is there an issue with the script itself?**

Comment: Which version of PyPDF2 do you use?

Comment: Can you share the pdf that causes the issue?

Comment: Please try to make a minimal complete example

Comment: Hey @MartinThoma  I'm sorry I forgot the golden rule. I am on 3.0.0. I can not share the exact pdfs that are used with these scripts, unfortunately. Let me try to make a succinct example that replicates.

Comment: My guess is that just calling `extract_text` is enough. Please try switching to `pypdf` and upgrading to the latest version. Shouldn't be hard

Comment: @MartinThoma I created a basic text extraction script in the same directory. It functions as expected for both PyPDF2 3.0.0 and pypdf 3.2.0 when using most files. However, there are 2 large files auto uploaded monthly for this script to split. One of the files works fine, the other throws the error in both 3.0.0 and pypdf 3.2.0. The first difference that I can see is that the font shows WinAnsiEncoding in the file that throws the error. It is Gill Sans MT for both files.

Comment: `PyPDF2==3.0.0` is essentially `pypdf==3.1.0`, but only `pypdf` will receive updates in future, so please focus on that. The issue you describe looks like a bug. I suggest that you add as much information as possible to the bugtracker: https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug&template=bug-report.md&title=

Comment: @MartinThoma sounds good. I will get started there. Thank you!